# How to open and manage an invisible activity within the main activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to open an invisible activity when my main activity starts, and to change its visibility with a button. Invisible activity is a custom popup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android

Comment: `Invisible activity is a custom popup.` Have you considered creating a Dialog instead? At one point only 1 activity can be active.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide its visibility by setting visibility="gone/invisible"

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```